# How to extract data from pandas.DataFrame.plot.kde?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
plot.confax(ax1)
ax1.set_ylabel('Extinction')
ax1.text(0.5, 0.8, 'Morning scatter',
          transform=ax1.transAxes,
          color='k', fontsize=8)
                
ax1 = dataframe.plot.kde()
```

How do I extract the data generated from `dataframe.plot.kde()`? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Looked at documentation, found nothing useful. Tried suggestions from other questions on stack overflow, but none work for me, I think because I am trying to extract data from an Axes object rather than a plot.

Comment: What do you mean by extracting data, get the KDE curve?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can implement a KDE by yourself:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Generate a random sample:

```
np.random.seed(12345)
sample = np.random.normal(size=1000)
```

Create a Random Variable that is defined by the KDE of the data:

```
KDE = stats.gaussian_kde(sample)
```

Sample over the domain:

```
xlin = np.linspace(-5, 5, 101)
```

Render as figure

```
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.hist(sample, density=1, bins=35)
axe.plot(xlin, KDE.pdf(xlin))
axe.grid()
```

[image]

Which renders as expected, KDE is a smooth and continuous version of the histogram of the dataset.